# Overriding equals() method in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, object, value-object

Short question: Why does Java allow overriding `equals()`, why is it not final?

I am reading Effective Java 2nd edition by Joshua Bloch.
I am a bit baffled by the conclusion that

> There is no way to extend an instantiable class and add a value component while preserving the equals contract

Is not it saying the same as `equals()` should be a `final` method?

The book gives an example of a class `A` with `equals()` method and then a class `AX` extending `A` having its own `equals()` method which is different from the `equals()` method in `A`.

I will not go into details of `equals()` in `A` and `equals()` in `AX`, but it suffices to say that they are **different**. Therefore we have inter-operatability problem which guarantees violation of transitivity and/or symmetry (maybe even something else) of `equals()` when we mix different implementations of `A` in some contexts (especially `HashSet`, `HashMap` type).

Thinking further, I don't think I can agree with with the conclusion that having something like

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null || o.getClass() != getClass())
      return false;
    ...
}
```

is wrong. I think this is precisely the proper way to deal with overriding `equals()`.

Java makes it possible so Java allows overriding `equals()` for a reason. If it had taken into account Liskov substitution principle in the strict sense, then it would not have allowed overriding `equals()` and implicitly makes any implementation of `equals()` final at the compiler level. What are your thoughts?

I can think of a case where composition is simply not suitable, and overriding `equals()` is the best option. This is the case where the class `A` is to be made persistent in a database and the context implies that there is no collection having both an implementation of `A` and subclasses of `A` such as `AX`.

Comment: Implementing equals and hashcode allows interning complex objects using hashtables.

Comment: is it possible that it's actually saying that the equals contract isn't suitable for many people's needs and that it's OK to break the contract in order to fulfil most developers' needs but that you should be aware that you are breaking a contract and the effects of that?

Comment: @David Scholefield I quoted the thing as pasted from the book. It says that Liskov substitution principle is part of the contract (but it is not). And thus breaking Liskov substitution principle means breaking the contract.

Comment: If `Object.equals()` were not overrideable, then it would be the same as `==`, and so would be redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: @user102008 That is not what I meant. I meant any **implementation** of `equals()` thus meaning subclasses of `Object` meaning not the `equals()` template method in `Object`. It will be trivially weird to make `equals()` final at that level.

Comment: This brings up another question about `compareTo()`. The book also suggests that `compareTo()` should also be `final` with similar argument. Now since there is no `compareTo()` in `Object`, I hope @user102008 can understand my question better.

Comment: `Java makes it possible so Java allows overriding equals() for a reason.` Language designers make mistakes too.

Comment: @InstructedA: There is no syntax or construct in Java (or any other language AFAIK) to make a method "overrideable once, but the override cannot be overridden" without the override choosing it as such.

Comment: @user102008 That is not correct. If the need is they can make a special case for it in the compiler, the same way they 'worked around' with the Clonable and Serializable interfaces

Comment: @Doval They don't even put that suggestion of 'final' in the documentation of the `compareTo()` nor `equals()`. People invent that version of Liskov thing, make it a 'principle' and then call heresy on those who do not follow it.

Comment: @InstructedA: There is *nothing* special compiler-wise about Cloneable and Serializable, except that arrays automatically implement both.

Comment: @InstructedA: Those interfaces don't specify any methods. (They are called "marker interfaces".) There is nothing special about that. Anyone can make any number of interfaces that don't have any methods.

Comment: @InstructedA: Adding lots of special cases for particular methods to the language is bad design.

Comment: Giving `Object` an `equals` method was a mistake because it presupposes that everything is comparable. That's not the case: you can't meaningfully compare functions (checking if two functions are equivalent is undecidable), or infinite streams  (you'd have to compare every element of both streams, which would never end). Exposing reference equality (`==`) was also a bad move because it breaks classes with value semantics. There's no way to tell two `5`s apart; it doesn't even make sense to ask if this `5` is different from that `5`. Yet you can tell two `new Integer(5)`s apart with `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`equals()` is a byproduct of an attempt to improve C++ when it was created.  C++ has operator overloading which allows you to perform custom operations when called with otherwise valid operators such as <, >, !=, ==, and even =.

The team made the decision (wisely so) to make equality be class method rather than having external static methods as it was done in C++.  However, this also meant that `equals()` coupled with `hashCode()` defined how such classes were handled in collection classes.

Since any class could in theory override `equals()` or `hashCode()`, it means that just because you have a collection of a certain type does not guarantee that behavior is uniform.

For instance, suppose class A has two members x and y used to determine equality.  Along comes class B which has x, y, and z.  If an instance of B had the same values x and y, how would you go about inserting this instance in a `Set`?  If you call the `equals` of an instance of A, it will determine the two to be equal and if you call the `equals` of an instance of B, it will return false since it is not an instance of B.

To be perfectly correct, class B would have to treat member z as an additional condition only in the case in which it is an instance of B, otherwise it lends itself to the `equals()` method of class A, and, if such a thing is not possible, class B should not allow itself to override `equals()` or `hashCode()`.  This creates a sticky situation since in theory you should not concern yourself with how the parent class works from an implementation standpoint (if done right anyway), but yet here we are.

You could make class A final to prevent such things from happening, but then of course you can never extend class A.  Java makes a point of making certain standard classes like String final to prevent complications of this nature (very smart decision on their part).  I think at the end of the day, what matters is that you are very careful in your usage of `equals()` and `hashCode()`.  I try to use it sparingly, and I am always mindful of which classes I mean to be available in a library and which classes are for internal use as to not to create conditions where things could go horribly wrong.

The Liskov substitution principle is fine in theory, but in practice you can never quite manage it.  Take `Collection` as an example.  `Collection` is implemented by `ArrayList`, `Set`, or `LinkedList` among others.  While it is true that you could achieve the same ultimate goal by replacing a `Collection` with say a `HashSet`, it is not an ideal implementation for performing operations on all objects contained within (better `LinkedHashSet` at that point).  It wouldn't break existing code, but you may potentially render it grossly inefficient depending on how that `Collection` is used.  Consider that this is a rather clean example too.

If you're lucky, only the implementation details change, but many behave radically different, with some methods throwing a `NotImplementedException`.

Thus requiring that classes implementing `equals()` must respect the Liskov substitution principle is asking a lot, and I suspect that they didn't want to alienate the majority of C++ programmers getting familiar with Java.

Comment: Thank you so much for spending time answering my question (+1). However, I hoping you can elaborate on my question of why `equals()` is not final. I do understand the situation you mentioned. My question is more on the line of: with what you say: why not add in the contract: 2 objects must be equal if the parent class "sections" are equal. (basically the Liskov substitution principle)

Comment: @InstructedA then it would fail as a value class. If I have two instances of B with the same z and y but different z, and they have to compare equal, then B isn't really a value class. In general, LSP requires that we can't really override classes to modify behavior, only extend behavior, and adding an extra value to a value class requires modifying behavior.

Comment: @InstructedA Updated answer.  :)

Comment: Excellent answer, but since this is exactly what I want to see I hope to see more so I can avoid confirmation bias.

Comment: @raptortech97 You seem to suggest that `we can't really override classes to modify behavior, only extend behavior` which means we should always call `super(...)` in any overriding methods. Is that correct?

Comment: @InstructedA not technically, but in practice that's generally how it's gonna have to work, yeah. This is one reason we favor composition over inheritance: proper LSP conformance is difficult and restrictive

Answer (score 3):

Simple argument against your logic is, what is the use of the equals method if it's modified to be a final. Then it would execute same logic against any given objects. If you want to compare A and AX in the object class what would be the logic?

Overriding of final method is allowed to be able to verify if two different objects (living in 2 different memory locations) are actually equals (== method is there to check if two references are of the same object) based on defined logic. For example if you have a user object like this,

```
User
{
    string name;
    string email;
    string phone;
}
```

For one system, it would be the email you might interest to uniquely identifying a user. So you may compare based on email value. But some other system might use phone as the unique identifier. So they may decide to implement different equals methods.

When it comes to logic of A,AX and Liksov substitution principle which is,

**Functions that use pointers or references to base classes must be able to use objects of derived classes without knowing it.**

So if you do,

```
AX ax1 = new AX();
AX ax2 = new AX();
ax1.equals(ax2);
```

and

```
A a = new AX();
AX ax = new AX();
a.equals(ax);
```

should give you the same output, and it will.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (+1). The logic in this question is about `A a1 = new A(x); A ax = new AX(x,y)` requires that `a1.equals(ax)`

Answer (score 1):

To give a short answer to your short question - it's because the equals() function defined for java.lang.Object is largely useless.  It's just equivalent to "==" in that it returns true if the two references refer to the same object, and doesn't really test if they are "equal" in the normal sense of the word.

Thus, if you actually want to compare two objects to see if they hold equal data, you need to override the default implementation of equals().  You normally should override hashCode() as well.

Comment: I hope you read my comments with @user102008 above. It will help you better understand my question. Thanks

Comment: I tend to work by pragmatism, rather than dogma.  The equals() function is meant to be overridden by design.  I would also not consider two objects of different classes ever to be equal, unless that was a deliberate intention of the designer of those classes (for instance where one class held cached data, and the other un-cached, but the underlying data was comparable).  I don't believe there is a serious issue with the Liskov substitution principle, so long as the derived classes still follow the derived class "is a" base class principle.

Comment: Me too, I also tend to work by pragmatism. Thanks for spending time answering me.

Comment: (+1) for trying to elaborate your point to me. Thanks again.